# How to create ensemble in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to create an ensemble of many trained models. All models have the same graph and just differ by its weights. I am creating the model graph using `tf.get_variable`. I have several different checkpoints (with different weights) for the same graph architecture and I want to make one instance model for each checkpoint.

How can I load many checkpoints without overwriting the previous loaded weights?

As I created my graphs with `tf.get_variable`, the only way I can create multiple graph is by passing the argument `reuse = True`. Now if I try changing the names of my graph variables enclosing the build method in a new scope (so they become non-sharable with other created graphs) before loading, then this is not going to work because the new names will differ from the saved weights and I will not be able to load it.

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but here is some reference code:
https://github.com/eske/seq2seq/blob/master/translate/__main__.py#L190

In short, the author creates as many sessions as many checkpoints, and within each session he restores corresponding checkpoint.

Comment: Some more relevant reference code: https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/05_Ensemble_Learning.ipynb

Comment: @cesarsalgado: I have same problem. I am using inception-v4 in tf-slim. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

This requires a few hacks. Let us save a few simple models

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
import tensorflow as tf


def build_graph(init_val=0.0):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=init_val)
    y = x + w
    return x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--init', help='dummy string', type=float)
    parser.add_argument('--path', help='dummy string', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    x1, y1 = build_graph(args.init)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(sess.run(y1, {x1: 10}))  # outputs: 10 + i

        save_path = saver.save(sess, args.path)
        print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)

# python ensemble.py --init 1 --path ./models/model1.chpt
# python ensemble.py --init 2 --path ./models/model2.chpt
# python ensemble.py --init 3 --path ./models/model3.chpt
```

These models produce outputs of "10 + i" where i=1, 2, 3.
Note this script creates, runs and saves multiple times the *same* graph-structure. Loading these values and restoring each graph individually is folklore and can be done by

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
import tensorflow as tf


def build_graph(init_val=0.0):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=init_val)
    y = x + w
    return x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--path', help='dummy string', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    x1, y1 = build_graph(-5.)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        saver.restore(sess, args.path)
        print("Model loaded from path: %s" % args.path)

        print(sess.run(y1, {x1: 10}))

# python ensemble_load.py --path ./models/model1.chpt  # gives 11
# python ensemble_load.py --path ./models/model2.chpt  # gives 12
# python ensemble_load.py --path ./models/model3.chpt  # gives 13
```

These produce again the outputs 11,12,13 like expected. Now the trick is to create for each model from the ensemble its own scope like

```py
def build_graph(x, init_val=0.0):
    w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=init_val)
    y = x + w
    return x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    models = ['./models/model1.chpt', './models/model2.chpt', './models/model3.chpt']
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    outputs = []
    for k, path in enumerate(models):
        # THE VARIABLE SCOPE IS IMPORTANT
        with tf.variable_scope('model_%03i' % (k + 1)):
            outputs.append(build_graph(x, -100 * np.random.rand())[1])
```

Hence each model lives under a different *variable*-scope, ie. we have variables 'model_001/w:0, model_002/w:0, model_003/w:0' although they have a similar (not the same) sub-graph, these variables are indeed different objects. Now, the trick is to manage two sets of variables (those of the graph under the current scope and those from the checkpoint):

```py
def restore_collection(path, scopename, sess):
    # retrieve all variables under scope
    variables = {v.name: v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scopename)}
    # retrieves all variables in checkpoint
    for var_name, _ in tf.contrib.framework.list_variables(path):
        # get the value of the variable
        var_value = tf.contrib.framework.load_variable(path, var_name)
        # construct expected variablename under new scope
        target_var_name = '%s/%s:0' % (scopename, var_name)
        # reference to variable-tensor
        target_variable = variables[target_var_name]
        # assign old value from checkpoint to new variable
        sess.run(target_variable.assign(var_value))
```

The full solution would be

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def restore_collection(path, scopename, sess):
    # retrieve all variables under scope
    variables = {v.name: v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scopename)}
    # retrieves all variables in checkpoint
    for var_name, _ in tf.contrib.framework.list_variables(path):
        # get the value of the variable
        var_value = tf.contrib.framework.load_variable(path, var_name)
        # construct expected variablename under new scope
        target_var_name = '%s/%s:0' % (scopename, var_name)
        # reference to variable-tensor
        target_variable = variables[target_var_name]
        # assign old value from checkpoint to new variable
        sess.run(target_variable.assign(var_value))


def build_graph(x, init_val=0.0):
    w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=init_val)
    y = x + w
    return x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    models = ['./models/model1.chpt', './models/model2.chpt', './models/model3.chpt']
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    outputs = []
    for k, path in enumerate(models):
        with tf.variable_scope('model_%03i' % (k + 1)):
            outputs.append(build_graph(x, -100 * np.random.rand())[1])

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        print(sess.run(outputs[0], {x: 10}))  # random output -82.4929
        print(sess.run(outputs[1], {x: 10}))  # random output -63.65792
        print(sess.run(outputs[2], {x: 10}))  # random output -19.888203

        print(sess.run(W[0]))  # randomly initialize value -92.4929
        print(sess.run(W[1]))  # randomly initialize value -73.65792
        print(sess.run(W[2]))  # randomly initialize value -29.888203

        restore_collection(models[0], 'model_001', sess)  # restore all variables from different checkpoints
        restore_collection(models[1], 'model_002', sess)  # restore all variables from different checkpoints
        restore_collection(models[2], 'model_003', sess)  # restore all variables from different checkpoints

        print(sess.run(W[0]))  # old values from different checkpoints: 1.0
        print(sess.run(W[1]))  # old values from different checkpoints: 2.0
        print(sess.run(W[2]))  # old values from different checkpoints: 3.0

        print(sess.run(outputs[0], {x: 10}))  # what we expect: 11.0
        print(sess.run(outputs[1], {x: 10}))  # what we expect: 12.0
        print(sess.run(outputs[2], {x: 10}))  # what we expect: 13.0

# python ensemble_load_all.py
```

Now having a list of *outputs*, you can average these values *within* TensorFlow or do some other ensemble predictions.

**edit**:

- It is way easier to store the model as a numpy dictionary using NumPy (npz) and load these values, like in my answer here:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181741/7443104
- The code above just illustrates a solution. It does not feature sanity checks (like does the variable really exists). A try-catch might help.

Comment: The answer doesn't cover the case when the models are already trained, and one wants to create a new model which is an ensemble of the trained models.

Comment: How shall we merge the input placeholders of different models?
In your answer, you have initialized a single placeholder, because you are creating the graphs right there and you have the luxury of setting that single placeholder as the input. But what if there were multiple graphs, each with their own input placeholder?

Comment: It is **exactly** the same then. You can construct the graph within `build_graph`. Just use the single placeholder or different as the input. Loading the weights do not change the graph and the graph can be modified before loading the weights. Then just do `tf.add_n(outputs)` or whatever you want to do in your ensemble. The trick is to place each model/previous graph into its own variable_scope and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions regarding this topic and a lot of possible answers/ways to do it. Here, I'd like to show how I came up with the most elegant and cleanest way of making an ensemble of `N` models, where `N` is arbitrary. This solution was tested with tf 1.12.0, python 2.7

The following code snippet is what you are looking for (comments below):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

num_of_ensembles = N
savers = list()
palceholders = list()
inference_ops = list()

for i in xrange(num_of_ensembles):
    with tf.name_scope('model_{}'.format(i)):
        savers.append(tf.train.import_meta_graph('saved_model.ckpt.meta'))

graph = tf.get_default_graph()

for i in xrange(num_of_ensembles):
    placeholders.append(graph.get_operation_by_name('model_{}/input_ph'.format(i)).outputs[0])
    inference_ops.append(graph.get_operation_by_name('model_{}/last_operation_in_the_network'.format(i)).outputs[0])


with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in xrange(num_of_ensembles):
        savers[i].restore(sess, 'saved_model.ckpt')
        prediction = sess.run(inference_ops[i], feed_dict={placeholders[i]: np.random.rand(your_input.shape)})
```

So, first thing to do is to import the meta graph of each model. As suggested in the comments above, the key is to create for each model from the ensemble its own scope, in order to add a prefix like *model_001/, model_002/ ...* to each variable scopes. This will allow you to restore `N` different models, with their own independent variables.

All this graphs will live in the current default graph. Now, when you load a model you have to extract the inputs, outputs, and operations that you wish to use from the graph into new variables. To do so, you'll need to know the names of those tensors from the old model. You can inspect all saved operations using the command: `ops = graph.get_operations()`. In the example above the first operation is the placeholder assignment */input_ph* while the last operation was named */last_operation_in_the_network* (normally, if the author of the network doesn't specify the field `name` per each layer, you will find something like */dense_3, /conv2d_1* etc.). Note that it must be the exact final operation of your model and, also, you must provide the **tensor** which is the value `.outputs[0]` of the operation itself.

Finally, you can run the session with the correct inference operation and placeholder, getting the prediction as numpy array and doing whatever you want (averaging, majority voting, etc.)

Useful links that you may want to check:

- [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/8hw2bf/how_to_restore_model_and_make_prediction_with_it/?depth=2)
- [A quick complete tutorial to save and restore Tensorflow models](https://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/)