# What's the diff between tf.import_graph_def and tf.train.import_meta_graph

Tags: tensorflow

When training in model folder there are auto saved meta graph files.
So what's the diff between graph and meta graph.
If I want to load model and do inference witout building graph from scratch,
use tf.train.import_meta_grah is fine?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find the answer from 
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/meta_graph/index.html
and 
[How to load several identical models from save files into one session in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828600/how-to-load-several-identical-models-from-save-files-into-one-session-in-tensorf)

And you can also refer to this:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4658