# Exporting Meta Graph from a checkpoint file Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Using `TF.slim` and the [pre-trained checkpoints](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models) I can evaluate the performance of a model. Also, using [exporting inference graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#exporting-the-inference-graph) I can freeze the model including its weights. However, I would like to find a way to export `.meta` file of a model as well. How can I do that using only the given the `.chpt` file? Say on the inception_v3 case.

Comment: Looks like you could modify [export_inference_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/export_inference_graph.py) to first load a checkpoint and then use [tf.train.export_meta_graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/export_meta_graph) instead of `graph.as_graph_def()`. Perhaps more of a feature request at that point (feel free to [file it](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/new)).

Comment: thanks, @AllenLavoie. Could you give me a MWE of your answer here? Thanks.

Comment: It's not an answer :). Please do file a feature request (or pull request!) for slim meta-graph saving; I think it's a good idea.

Comment: I did already here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2986